# DateField in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I used DateField in a Form. When I try to select a date it opens up calendar functionality provided by cellphone.

As you know the UI features in j2me are not that great. I looked at third party libraries to design fancy UI. So far I have not found any api which makes DateField fancy. Is anybody aware of any API which supports DateField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the phone's native control for this is exactly what j2me is supposed to do.
The system has clear advantages when changing the phone language, especially when the alphabet isn't in basic ASCII characters.

If you want to control exactly the way the calendar looks, you'll need to draw it yourself in a Canvas and deal with user input, screen size and localization issues yourself.

In general, you might want to look into the LWUIT library for an intermediary solution between fixed native controls and direct screen access.